# MongoDB C# driver stop Authentation Failure retries

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Just learning how to use MongoDB C# driver and wondering why the 'MongoClient' tries to continually reconnect with wrong credentials?

How do I stop auto-connect and deal with 'MongoAuthenticationException' so a user can try to log back in?

```
namespace MongoDBConsole
{
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsyc().Wait();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MainAsyc()
    {
        var pw = "admin";
        var sPwd = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in pw)
        {
            sPwd.AppendChar(c);
        }

        var settings = new MongoClientSettings()
        {
            Credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("admin", "admin", sPwd)
        };

        var client = new MongoClient(settings);
    }
}
```

}

Mongo log

```
2018-10-06T02:33:00.354+1000 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53063 conn3: { driver: { name: "mongo-csharp-driver", version: "2.7.0.0" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134", architecture: "x86_32", version: "10.0.17134" }, platform: ".NET Framework 4.7.3163.0" }
2018-10-06T02:33:00.409+1000 I ACCESS   [conn3] SASL SCRAM-SHA-256 authentication failed for admin on admin from client 127.0.0.1:53063 ; AuthenticationFailed: SCRAM authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
2018-10-06T02:33:00.409+1000 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:53063 (0 connections now open)
2018-10-06T02:33:00.410+1000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53064 #4 (1 connection now open)
2018-10-06T02:33:00.410+1000 I NETWORK  [conn4] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53064 conn4: { driver: { name: "mongo-csharp-driver", version: "2.7.0.0" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134", architecture: "x86_32", version: "10.0.17134" }, platform: ".NET Framework 4.7.3163.0" }
2018-10-06T02:33:00.468+1000 I ACCESS   [conn4] SASL SCRAM-SHA-256 authentication failed for admin on admin from client 127.0.0.1:53064 ; AuthenticationFailed: SCRAM authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
2018-10-06T02:33:00.469+1000 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:53064 (0 connections now open)
```

Comment: looks like I was able to to kill client by `client.cluster.dispose()`, then `client=null`, cluster property appears to be unmanaged.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across the same issue I believe the solution is

```
client.cluster.dispose();
client = null
```

Then create new client when required, e.g. new credentials

```
    var settings = new MongoClientSettings()
    {
        Credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("admin", "admin", sPwd)
    };

    var client = new MongoClient(settings);
```